# How can I set columns=fixed for lstinline globally?

Tags: spacing, listings

I typeset my listings using [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) with a proportional font. This looks good for the `lstlisting` environment. However, when I use `\lstinline|code|`, the spacing reverts to variable-width. I would like to use the setting `columns=fixed` with `lstinline`. If I `\lstset` it globally, it is ignored for `\lstinline`. Is there a way to set `\lstinline` to use `columns=fixed` without having to add it to every `\lstinline` in my source code?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fixed}

\begin{document}
The code \lstinline|A.someMethodName()| is typeset differently from
\lstinline[columns=fixed]|A.someOtherMethodName()|.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `\lstMakeShortInline` command to pass the `columns=fixed` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{columns=fixed}
\lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|

\begin{document}
The code \lstinline|A.someMethodName()| is typeset differently from
\lstinline[columns=fixed]|A.someOtherMethodName()|. Using \verb+\lstMakeShortInline[columns=fixed]|+ you get the expected result:
|A.someMethodName()|

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and by reading through the documentation, I tried setting the `keepspaces=true` option in `\lstset{...}` and it seems to have the desired effect! Spaces are no longer eaten up ;-)

Comment: It makes no difference with the code in the question. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: +1 I tried both and prefer this solution. For me, `columns=fixed` adds to much space between characters, which is ok for code blocks but looks weird for inline code. `keepspaces=true` does exactly what promised: it keeps spaces from disappearing without changing anything else. I used it as option to `lstMakeShortInline` though, not for `lstset`.