# Sources to be copied from PDF

Tags: listings, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Phantom spaces in listings (pdf)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4911/phantom-spaces-in-listings-pdf)

I would like to create PDF using luatex and it's important that listings where copied from this PDF in the original form (to keep them working). For example, there is the row in SQL:

```
insert into msg_dictionary (MSG_TYPE, COMMAND_CODE, INTERNAL_PRIORITY, MIN_LEVEL, MAX_LEVEL, UNLOCK_SIZE, MAX_LOCKED_AMOUNT, DENIAL_BODY)
values ('0105404', '0100', 3, 0, 3, 1, 10, null);
```

using package `listings` created pdf, but when i select the code and paste it to editor i get:

```
i n s e r t i n t o m s g _ d i c t i o n a r y ( MSG_TYPE , COMMAND_CODE ,
INTERNAL_PRIORITY , MIN_LEVEL , MAX_LEVEL , UNLOCK_SIZE ,
MAX_LOCKED_AMOUNT , DENIAL_BODY )
v a l u e s ( ’ 0105404 ’ , ’ 0100 ’ , 3 , 0 , 3 , 1 , 1 0 , n u l l ) ;
```

How can this issue be solved?

Comment: Is it related to (La)TeX and its friends?

Comment: Yes, because PDF generated by latex and his friends.

Comment: @Damien Yes.  And it's also a duplicate: [Phantom spaces in listings (pdf)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4911/2693). See also [How can I set columns=fixed for lstinline globally?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18308/2693)